# Deployment fails with GoogleAppEngineLauncher (HTML & CSS Files not uploaded)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, upload

I am working on a larger project with Google App Engine in Python. I am using the GoogleAppEngineLauncher on a Mac. Everything works fine with .py files.

But when I change HTML or CSS files, sometimes they are not uploaded to the cloud, when I press the deploy button

It is not that .html or .css files are excluded from uploads. New files with those endings are always uploaded. But changed files are not uploaded at all or only when I try this later during the day. I checked modification times and timezone settings on my local machine. Everything seems to be setup correctly.

Comment: You may find the css and static files can be cached in places you have no control over.  Try using cache busting techniques to prove if this is the case or not.

Comment: If you use the Pagespeed service, did you flush the cache.

Comment: I did not use the Pagespeed service.